# Copying/Saving certain data entered in one sheet of excel to another sheet and storing it as a database

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheet1 which looks like a form and data is entered in specific cells, On clicking a button the data entered must goto sheet2 in a row. Again when next set of datas are entered in sheet1 and button is pressed the datas should go to the next non empty row of sheet 2.
Kindly help me out.

```
Sub Button5_Click() 
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("h9") 
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("h10") 
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("h11") 
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("h12") 
End Sub
```

This code replaces specific cells again and again, What should i do in order for it to take the location by itself and append new dat

Comment: Please note Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You need to show your current attempt and explain what exactly doesn't work and what have you already done to try to improve/fix it.

Comment: Sub Button5_Click()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("h9")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("h10")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("h11")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("h12")

End Sub This code replaces specific cells again and again, What should i do in order for it to take the location by itself and append new data in next row

Comment: Your posted code does the opposite of what you say you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Button5_Click() 
dim s1,s2

    Set s1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    with s1.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0).entirerow

        .cells(,"a").Value = s2.Range("h9").Value 
        .cells(,"b").Value = s2.Range("h10").Value  
        .cells(,"c").Value = s2.Range("h11").Value  
        .cells(,"d").Value = s2.Range("h12").Value  

    End with

End Sub
```

Comment: Sub Button5_Click()
Dim s1, s2
Dim emptyRow As Long

    Set s1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
    With s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

        s1.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = s2.Range("h9").Value
        s1.Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = s2.Range("h10").Value
        s1.Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = s2.Range("h11").Value
        s1.Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = s2.Range("h12").Value

    End With

End Sub
Thank you for your reply, ive modified the code slightly and im not able to get the result

Comment: I require the new data from sheet1 to go to the next row, but this set of command replaces the existing data.

Comment: Your code totally works fine.. some syntactical errors were don by me.. Thank you again.